# Detemine the unit digit of a number

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Find the unit digit of the number:
$$3^{7005} \times 6^{8000}$$
My turn:
$$3^{7005}\times 6^{8000}=3^{7005}\times 3^{8000} \times2^{8000}$$ $$3^{13005} \times 2^{8000}$$
But i could not go on ?

Comment: Well, you can start by the fact that the last digit of $6^n$ is always $6$ for any positive whole number $n$. Then you only have the $3^{7005}$ to deal with.

Answer (score 4):

The unit digit of the numbers of the powers of $3$ form a cyclic sequence: $1,3,9,7,1,3,9,7,\ldots$ In particular, the unit digit of $3^n$ is $3$ if $n$ is of the form $4k+1$. And the unit digit of *any* power of $6$ is $6$. Since $7\,005$ is of the form $4k+1$, the answer to your question is $8(=3\times6\pmod{10})$.

Comment: Agreed! I wonder why someone downvoted ...

Comment: It happens all the time: :-(

Comment: Maybe the down-voter, like me, can't parse the sentence beginning with "In particular..."?  Oh, I just got it.  "of" is "if".

Comment: @B.Goddard Oops! I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

We want the unit digit of the number $3^{7005} \cdot6^{8000}$. This  is equivalent to asking for the residue of the number $3^{7005} \cdot6^{8000}$ modulo $10$. Hence, we want some number $n$ with $0 \leq n \leq 9$ such that
$$
n \equiv 3^{7005} \cdot6^{8000} \pmod{10}
$$

Note that $3^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$ and $6^n \equiv 6 \pmod{10}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. With this result, we have
\begin{align}
3^{7005} \cdot6^{8000} &= 3^{7004}\cdot 3^{1} \cdot 6^{8000} \\
&= \left(3^{4}\right)^{1751}\cdot 3^{1} \cdot 6^{8000}\\
&\equiv1^{1751}\cdot 3^{1} \cdot 6^{1} \pmod{10} \\
&= 3 \cdot 6 \\
&\equiv 8 \pmod{10} \\
\end{align}
Hence, the unit digit of $3^{7005} \cdot6^{8000}$ is $8$.

Comment: Right outcome, slight error in reasoning. $3^4\equiv 1 \mod 10;\ 3^7\equiv 7 \mod 10$. You figured it out right when you found $3^5\equiv 3 \mod 10$. Note that $4\mid 7004$.

Comment: @KeithBackman I'm shocked I overlooked that. I've edited my response with your correction. Thanks for reviewing my answer so closely!

Comment: Not to worry -- you should see some of the bloopers I've made!

Answer (score 1):

If you think about the way you typically do multiplication, the unit digit of a product is the product of the unit digits.

Can you figure out the unit digit of the two terms in the product?

Hint: calculate $3^0, 3^1, 3^2, 3^3, 3^4, 3^5,\ldots$  Do you see a pattern in the unit digits?  Do you see why the pattern holds?